# Почему не работают сесии Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Controller

```
    if ($company == null) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', ['Внимание! ...']);
    }
```

View

```
    @if(session()->has('error'))
       <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">x</a>
          {{ session()->get('error') }}
    </div>
    @endif
```

Просто обновление страницы происходит

Answer (score 0):

1) Проверьте в app/http/kernel.php включен ли middleware сессии в группу web.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \\ там еще много middleware 
        ],
```

1.1)Так же убедитесь, что эта группа включена по-умолчанию (в некоторых версиях с этим есть проблемы вроде). В app\providers\routeServiceProviders

```
public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }


    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```

2) Как вариант, но не совсем удачный, включить middleware сессий в глобальную группу в app/http/kernel.php:

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        \\Добавить
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,

        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
       \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,

    ];
```

3) Еще один вариант: мне кажется, там не массив передавать нужно, а  string.

Вместо:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('error', ['Внимание! ...']);
```

Надо:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Внимание! ...');
```

Comment: Проверил все пункты и даже добавил в protected $middleware = [...]